# I want to count distinct words in document using linux command?

Tags: linux, tr

For below data set I tried with using uniq command but did not get satisfactory result

```
Meredith Norris Thomas;Regular Air;HomeOffice
Kara Pace;Regular Air;HomeOffice
Ryan Foster;Regular Air;HomeOffice
```

Code:

```
cat HomeOffice_sales.txt |tr " " "\n" | tr ";" "\n"| uniq -c
```

result I got was wrong as `Air,Regular,HomeOffice` word is thrice(expected 3 Home office) :

```
      1 Meredith
      1 Norris
      1 Thomas
      1 Regular
      1 Air
      1 HomeOffice
      1 Kara
      1 Pace
      1 Regular
      1 Air
      1 HomeOffice
      1 Ryan
      1 Foster
      1 Regular
      1 Air
      1 HomeOffice
```

Comment: Why do you have `{}` around the command? That won't work like that.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried to put it in code block..I have removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uniq` only counts repeated lines that are together in the input, so you need to sort before piping to `uniq`.

```
tr ' ;' '\n\n' < HomeOffice_sales.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

You don't need multiple `tr` commands, you can give a list of input and output characters.